# CoreData ValueTransformer.transformedValueClass() is never called in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a `ValueTransformer` subclass that converts dates to strings to preserve the original time zone of the date in Core Data.

`transformedValue` and `reverseTransformedValue` are both called as expected, but the class func `transformedValueClass()` is not called.

I'm guessing the ValueTransformer is defaulting to use `NSData` because the error message I get when trying to persist values after save is:

> [__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here are the relevant bits of my code:

```
@objc(DateValueTransformer)
class DateValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    private let formatter = DateFormatterCache.sharedInstance.formatterWithFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        print("Anybody home??? Never called...")
        return NSDate.self
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let date = value as? Date else {
            return nil
        }

        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let dateString = value as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        return formatter.date(from: dateString)
    }
}
```

This is how the ValueTransformer is registered in CoreData:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code that calls your class?

Comment: When you set a ValueTransformer inside the xcdatamodel file, CoreData calls this class internally.  There is no user code that explicitly calls this class.

Comment: @jimj class functions are called like -: (classname.methodname). Here class name is the name of your class in which you have created your method.e example-: DateValueTransformer.transformedValueClass().

Comment: @TusharSharma I'm not sure I understand your point.  This is an overridden static function that should be automatically called by CoreData.  I'm not calling this method directly.

Comment: @jimj I haven't used it but this might help-: http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://bluelemonbits.com/index.php/2016/02/07/using-nsvaluetransformers-value-transformer-swift-2-0/&grqid=UCENWr_K&hl=en-IN

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for the link, but this is detailing how to use ValueTransformers with Cocoa bindings.  In that case you have to register the transformer for it to work.  When using ValueTransformers with Core Data, it's registered by adding it to the xcdatamodel file.  See screenshot I attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Core Data only supports transforming to NSData.  I couldn't find the original documentation for this in the Core Data programming guide but after much searching other users have encountered the same issue.

> The idea behind transformable attributes is that you access an
>   attribute as a non-standard type, but behind the scenes Core Data uses
>   an instance of NSValueTransformer to convert the attribute to and from
>   an instance of NSData. Core Data then stores the data instance to the
>   persistent store.
>
> By default, Core Data uses the NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName
>   transformer, however you can specify your own transformer if you want.
>   If you specify a custom transformer, it must transform an instance of
>   the non-standard data type into an instance of NSData and support
>   reverse transformation. You should not specify a name if you are using
>   the default transformer.

Answer (score 1):

The transformedValue function expects you to return an object in a format in which it can be saved on the filesystem, you are returning String object and it's not a type in which it can be stored, if you return this

```
override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {

    if let value = value {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: (value))

    }

    return nil
}
```

it will work as it will return the encoded form of the value which in your case is Date.